# Missing mysql.h and trying to find mysql-devel

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, r, rmysql

(I've been through four or five questions that are related to mine, but this sticking point I run into doesn't seem to be addressed in them.)

In trying to run RMySQL on RStudio on a windows machine, I've been trying to follow the help given here: [How to Connect R with MySQL or how to install RMySQL package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292326/how-to-connect-r-with-mysql-or-how-to-install-rmysql-package) and here: [Using MySQL in R for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223113/using-mysql-in-r-for-windows)

I was able to complete steps 1,3,4,5 but not #2.

I've tried searching for the missing header **mysql.h** itself, but everything I find is for a different platform, or else points toward http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads , where I honestly cannot see any reference to the header at all.

Another suggestion I saw was to install mysql-devel, but again, all the links I found for this pointed to nothing that worked.

Thanks in advance for your help: I hope it's simple to resolve!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the [MySQL Community Server](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/?product=community) and install it on your system. It contains a directory called `include` in which you find the `mysql.h`. You can also download the ZIP file version of the application and use it to obtain the header without installing anything to your system. Using the header from this package, I've [successfully built RMySQL in the past](http://martin.von-gagern.net/howtos/20110728-rmysql/).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the header this time, but RMySQL is still proving to be nearly impossible to install :(