# How do I install RODBC on Mac with unixodbc and freetds?

Tags: macos, rodbc, unixodbc, osx-yosemite

After a fairly extensive search, I noticed that a number of people are having a hard time finding a start-to-finish guide that answers this question. (At least [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214529/1775603) notes that a solution exists, but the proposed solution does not get around the fact that, by default, RODBC attempts to compile against iODBC, which is not included with Yosemite.) I just went through this process, so I thought I would document it here in the hope that it will benefit others. I am connecting to a SQL Server database.

Comment: Thanks, hrbrmstr. Excellent advice. I just made the change from my iPhone, but I'll double-check it when I get on my laptop again. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include in your question some of the errors/issues others have encountered? That will increase the probability they'll find this question if they search.

Comment: Not sure if you heard, there is [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver) package which is different from [RSQLServer](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer) shared on CRAN. The first one offers more native driver to sql server, should provide better speed than ODBC or JDBC. Not sure if it works on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. I will do this as soon as I am able to get back on my laptop. Great idea.

Comment: Thanks, Jangorecki. I checked out the second option you mentioned but  not the first. I will give it a look as soon as I have the chance.

Comment: Related: [Installing ODBC via HomeBrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199658/22781).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) as my OS X package manager, I can install `RODBC` with the following steps (assuming I have already installed [R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)).

1. Install `unixodbc`:

   ```
   $ brew install unixodbc
   ```
2. Install `freetds` (replacing `/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1` with your `unixodbc` directory, if necessary):

   ```
   $ brew install --with-tdsver=8.0 --with-msdblib --with-unixodbc=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1 freetds
   ```
3. Configure your `freetds` installation (the following is a minimal configuration file):

   #### `freetds.conf`

   ```
   # server specific section
   [global]
   ;       tds version = 8.0
   ;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
   ;       debug flags = 0xffff
   ;       timeout = 10
   ;       connect timeout = 10
           text size = 64512

   [TESTSQL]
           # insert the actual host below
           host = <xxx.xx.x.xx>
           port = 1433
           tds version = 8.0
   ```
4. Test the `freetds` config:

   ```
   $ tsql -H `<xxx.xx.x.xx>` -p 1433 -U `<username>` -P `<password>`
   ```

   > ```
   > locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
   > locale charset is "UTF-8"
   > using default charset "UTF-8"
   > 1> exit
   > ```
5. Configure your `unixodbc` installation (the following is a minimal configuration file):

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini
   ```

   #### `odbcinst.ini`

   ```
   [MSSQL]
   Description   = Microsoft SQL Server driver
   Driver        = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.18/lib/libtdsodbc.so
   ```

   (and another minimal installation file):

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
   ```

   #### `odbc.ini`

   ```
   [ODBC Data Sources]
   TESTSQL     = Test database

   [TESTSQL]
   Driver      = MSSQL
   Servername  = TESTSQL
   Port        = 1433
   Database    = TMSEPRD
   TDS_Version = 8.0
   ```
6. Test the new configuration with `isql`:

   ```
   $ isql TESTSQL `<username>` `<password>`
   ```

   > ```
   > +---------------------------------------+
   > | Connected!                            |
   > |                                       |
   > | sql-statement                         |
   > | help [tablename]                      |
   > | quit                                  |
   > |                                       |
   > +---------------------------------------+
   > SQL> quit
   > ```
7. Create a symbolic link to the files in your home directory:

   ```
   $ ln -vs /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.18/etc/freetds.conf ~/.freetds.conf
   $ ln -vs /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
   $ ln -vs /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini
   ```
8. Find and modify your `RProfile` file by appending the following line(s) of code to the file (replacing `/usr/local/include` with the include directory that contains your `sql.h` and `sqlext.h` files; the second line may be unnecessary if the directory does not exist):

   ```
   $ vim /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/base/R/Rprofile
   Sys.setenv(ODBC_INCLUDE="/usr/local/include")
   Sys.setenv(ODBC_LIBS="/usr/local/lib")
   ```
9. Now download the `RODBC` package source (which you an download [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html)) to your Downloads folder.
10. Open a new R console session and install the package (replacing `RODBC_1.3-12.tar.gz` with the name of your package source):

    > install.packages("~/Downloads/RODBC_1.3-12.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")

The package should now work:

```
> library(RODBC)
> myconn <- odbcConnect("TESTSQL", uid="<userid>", pwd="<password>")
```

Thanks to [Jared Folkins](http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-freetds-and-unixodbc-on-osx-using-homebrew-for-use-with-ruby-php-and-perl/) and [Gabi Huiber](http://www.enoriver.net/2015/03/29/i-got-rodbc-to-work-on-yosemite-too/) for help with figuring out what directories R looks in by default for the requisite files for RODBC.

Comment: see, macs are easy! thanks for this...spent way too much time wrestling with this.

Comment: I used steps 1-6 to get package odbc working with a MSSQL database. Note that the [servername] in freetds.conf has to be different from the [differentservername] in odbc.ini !