# Install RODBC package in R with MacOS 10.13.3 - High Sierra

Tags: r, macos, rodbc, macos-high-sierra

I've been trying to install the RODBC package in R Studio on MacOS 10.13.3 - High Sierra, but I've not succeeded yet.

I tried to follow some answers for previous versions of MacOS here on Stack, but none worked, not even this one:

[how to install RODBC on macOS Sierra 10.12.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804850/how-to-install-rodbc-on-macos-sierra-10-12-4)

I'm also kind of new to MacOS, so I would appreciate some simple procedure.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not programming related. We'll vote to close it (and migrate it to https://superuser.com or maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There appear to be several other questions about this problem which you should read first. You already found one, here's another. You're not going to get more help by just saying "It didn't work". Read, try and research what others have written and then come back with **specific** questions if you still don't understand. Good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210317/installation-of-rodbc-roracle-packages-on-os-x-mavericks?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You have posted nothing of what you did, nothing about versions and source of the recommended system package outside R, nothng about environment variables you may or amy not have set, pretty much .... nothing. I have often found the process of writing up a properly documented question allows me to solve questions without posting.