# Unable to connect MySQL using R

Tags: java, mysql, r

I'm learning R language. I want to establish a connection with `MySQL` using `R`. I've studied how to do from [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mysql-through-r/), [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/mysql-and-r/), [tutorial](https://mkmanu.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/r-and-mysql-a-tutorial-for-beginners/) and from many other websites. I've followed all the steps to connect with MySQL, but still I'm unable to connect with MySQL, and getting an error:

```
  Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)
```

Here is screenshot of what I did:
[image: work done and error]

I'm using `R version-3.2.2` and `MySQL version-5.6` and MySQL database is running on `localhost:1527`. Please help me to remove the error and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**INFO:** I'm `able` to connect above MySQL database with `java`.

Comment: Please read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292326/how-to-connect-r-with-mysql-or-how-to-install-rmysql-package), as there appears to be a bit more configuration than what you have done above.

Comment: Intuitively, it should make sense that the R package won't know where to look for your MySQL database out of the box without you telling it where to look.

Comment: Do you mean I've to set classpath variables. (Sorry for asking silly question)

Comment: Your question isn't silly actually.  Yes, I believe you have to configure some environment variables.  Work through that post and then come back here if you still can't get it to work.  It's good that your JDBC code works, because at least we know that there is nothing wrong with your MySQL instance.

Comment: maybe run `Sys.getenv()` to see the `MySQL` path

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've followed all the steps mentioned in your link but still can't...

Comment: What output do you get in R console from this: `Sys.getenv(c("R_HOME", "MYSQL_HOME", "PATH"))` ?

Comment: I got following output

R_HOME  
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2"  
MYSQL_HOME  
"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\MySQL\\\\MySQL Server 5.6\""
along with my complete path

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for ur support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say that your mysql is running on `localhost:1527` - but you don't specify that port in `dbConnect`, then it probably uses the default port, `3306`, so it should not be able to connect... add the port argument to your dbConnect

```
dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="password", dbname="dbname", host="localhost", port="1527")
```